# C++ How to create and return an iterator inside a function?

Tags: c++, iterator

I tried to write a function that receives a list and an index and returns an iterator to the list that starts at that index.

The function:

```
template<class T>
typename std::list<T>::iterator begin_it_at_index(list<T> list_to_iterate_on, const int index)
{
  return next(list_to_iterate_on.begin(), index);
}
```

When I called the function to get the iterator, I did get the first element I wanted at the correct index, but when I did "++" on the iterator it just jumped out of the list instead of going to the next element.

The code:

```
list<int> temp = {10,20,50,100};
  for (auto it = begin_it_at_index(temp, 1); it != temp.end(); ++it)
  {
    cout << *it << endl;
  }
```

The output:

```
20
74211408
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the container *by reference* to `begin_it_at_index`. Otherwise a value copy is taken, and the returned iterator is invalidated as the local `list_to_iterate_on` in the function goes out of scope.

That is,

```
template<class T>
typename std::list<T>::iterator begin_it_at_index(
    list<T>& list_to_iterate_on,
    const int index
)
```

is a fix.

Comment: Thank you Bathsheba, the fix worked